# Bash - replace all files, of a certain type, recursively, with a single file, retaining the original file name

Tags: bash, recursion, replace

Suppose I have a directory that I need to traverse recursively, finding each file of a certain type (*.jpeg), and replace each matching occurrence with one unique file (placeholder.jpeg) BUT I want to keep the original filename.

I am replacing all jpeg images in a large directory structure with one small placeholder image, but I need to keep the original file names intact.

So a recursive find-file-by-type-and-replace, but keeping the original file name.

Here is what almost works:

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for f in /tmp/**/*.jpeg
do
 cp /tmp/placeholder.jpeg $f
done
```

Comment: *Almost works* is not a good description, what is the problem you are actually facing? Perhaps just quote the expansions: `"$f"`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me that your placeholder file is always outside the directory structure where you're doing the replacement.

Various `find` versions have a `-samefile` option to detect a particular file, so you could avoid an invocation of `cp` that's going to emit its "... are the same file" warning:

```
find /tmp \
    -name '*.jpeg' ! -samefile /tmp/placeholder.jpeg \
    -exec cp /tmp/placeholder.jpeg  {} \;
```

You could test by replacing `-exec cp ...` with `-exec echo cp ...` to see the expected copies without doing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `find /tmp/ -name \*.jpeg -print0 | xargs -0I'{}' cp placeholder.jpeg {}`

Comment: Very close.  This works:

find /tmp/ -name \*.jpg -print0 | xargs -0I'{}' cp /tmp/thumb.jpg {}

Comment: Ha! Right, I'll fix it.